# Axios get request can't convert undefined to object

Tags: javascript, axios, svelte

I am trying to make a get request in my js/svelte application.
The REST-API works perfectly fine in the browser or when testing with postman.

When I click the Go button on the website then the following error ocours in the console from the inspection tool.

> Uncaught TypeError: can't convert undefined to object
>
> mergeConfig mergeConfig.js:92
> request Axios.js:39
> method Axios.js:129
> wrap bind.js:9
> login Login.svelte:11
> listen index.mjs:412
> listen_dev index.mjs:1961
> mount bundle.js:3413
> mount_component index.mjs:1745
> update bundle.js:765
> update bundle.js:931
> update index.mjs:1075
> flush index.mjs:1042
> promise callback*schedule_update index.mjs:1000
> make_dirty index.mjs:1777
> ctx index.mjs:1815
> unsubscribeLoc bundle.js:1442
> subscribe index.mjs:50
> instance$3 Router.svelte:493
> init index.mjs:1809
> Router bundle.js:1583
> create_fragment bundle.js:3583
> init index.mjs:1824
> App bundle.js:3655
> app main.js:3
>  bundle.js:3675

And this is the code.

```
    <script>
    import {replace} from 'svelte-spa-router'
    import {LoginDto} from "../scripts/data_transfer_objects/LoginDto";
    import axios from "axios";

    let loginTemplate = new LoginDto();

    function login(){
        console.log(loginTemplate.password);
        axios.get("http://localhost:5000/login", {
            auth: {
                username: "test",
                password: "1234"
            }
        });
        replace("#/activities");
    }
</script>

<div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" bind:value={loginTemplate.password}>
    <button on:click={login}>Go</button>
</div>
```

Does someone have a idea what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I tryied it with a even simpler example.

```
<script>
    import axios from "axios";

    axios.get("localhost:5000/activities");
</script>
```

This does not work either.
I prduces the same error as described above.

Comment: This does not  work either. I am pretty sure its oke to pass a auth: {} with a get request. It works when using postman.

Comment: What version of axios?

Comment: "axios": "^0.24.0",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may come from an outdated dependency on `@rollup/plugin-commonjs`. Upgrading from `17.0.0` to `21.0.1` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to log what the server return. You might know what happened.

```js
axios.get("http://localhost:5000/login", {
  auth: {
           username: "test",
           password: "1234"
        }
}).then(response => console.log(response));
```

Comment: The request doesn't get to the server, the error ocours before hands. But i have tryied it and i still get the same error.